# tagit "tags" method not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using tag it .... and below is htecode i am using to get all the tags but show how it dosent seem to work:-

```
    $("#demo2GetTags").click(function() {
        showTags($("#tags").tagit("tags"))
    });

    function showTags(tags) {
        console.log(tags);
        var string = "Tags (label : value)\r\n";
        string += "--------\r\n";
        for ( var i in tags)
            string += tags[i].label + " : " + tags[i].value + "\r\n";
        alert(string);
    }
```

Any idead...?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#demo2GetTags").click(function() {
    showTags($("#tags").tagit("assignedTags"))
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown